# Magento - How to display all user fields on registration form?

Tags: forms, magento

when I go to Customers -> Manage Customers -> Add New Customer, I see that there are Telephone,Zip, Country, and state fields. When I go to my frontend website the click 'Register', I see only First Name, Last Name, Email address, and password.

How do I display Telephone, Zip, Country, and state fields on my front end?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see those fields on the normal customer form, so I suspect that you may be referring to the customer grid rather than the new customer form. Those other fields are related to the customer's default billing address, which isn't captured immediately on registration (it may not be needed, more fields decrease registration, etc). If you want to add this information by default, you will probably need to look at adding a default address for a customer when they sign up.

Keep in mind, however, that other fields (notably street address) are required when adding those addresses.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe